# Nested vertical UICollectionView and dynamic height

Tags: swift, nested, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a parent UICollectionView that nests 2 other UICollectionViews:

- Parent UICollectionView (Vertical)

  - First nested UICollectionView (Horizontal) - Grey
  - Second nested UICollectionView (Vertical) - Red

[image: Parent and nested UICollectionViews]

### The parent UICollectionView

1. I use `numberOfSections(in collectionView:)` and manually set the number of sections in the parent collection view. In this case I `return 2`; one for first (grey) nested **horizontal** UICollectionView and one for the second (red) nested **vertical** UICollectionView
2. Then in `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int)` I `return 1`. That means each nested UICollectionView will be placed inside a single item.
3. For each section I dequeue `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` a specific cell [see **Nested UICollectionViews step 3**] for the first nested horizontal UICollectionView and a specific cell [see **Nested UICollectionViews step 3**] for the second nested vertical UICollectionView.
4. Then I set the size of each item in section using `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`. **This is where my problem begins. But let me continue on how I setup the nested UICollectionViews**.

## Nested UICollectionViews

This is a 3-step procedure for each nested UICollectionView:

1. I create the UICollectionViewCell (the appearance of the cell)
2. I use a UICollectionViewController to:

   - Fetch the data from Firebase
   - Dequeue the cell mentioned in step 1 and pass in the data fetched from Firebase
   - Set the dimensions of each item using `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`
3. I create another UICollectionViewCell that:

   - Initializes the UICollectionViewController mentioned in step 2
   - Uses the view of this UICollectionViewController and adds it to the cell's `contentView` by filling the superview (aka the cell)

     `contentView.addSubview(UICollectionViewController().view) UICollectionViewController().view.fillSuperview()`

## The problem

When I set the dimensions of the section where the horizontal UICollectionView (grey) will be, I just need to match the height of the UICollectionView to the height of each cell.

[image: vertical collection view height is equal to the cell height]

But when I set the dimensions of the section where the vertical UICollectionView will be (red) I need to know the number of cells to calculate the correct height. Otherwise, the section could either be too big or too small.

[image]

Any idea how I can notify the parent UICollectionView controller of the number of cells of the vertical nested collection view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For those nested behaviours I recommend creating `UICollectionView` by code, instead of IB Storyboard, so you do not have to deal so much with autoresizing constraints. You can create `UICollectionView` programmatically (instead of `UICollectionViewController` with desired `frame.size` and then assigning `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to  it so you can better controll how big should be your item layout in your nested collectionView based on its frame. Some example code is here:

```
    lazy var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = self.frame.size
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    return layout
}()

lazy var customCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.width * 0.5), collectionViewLayout: self.layout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    let collectionCellNib = UINib.init(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: Bundle.main)
    collectionView.register(collectionCellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "customCellId")
    return collectionView
}()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! I always do UI programmatically (team Brian Voong here :)) Since my parent UICollectionview controller will host a lot of different types of nested UICollectionViews I want to separate each nested UICollectionView. So the data fetching is done in each nested collection view. What I need is a way to pass this information (actually the number of articles received from Firebase) from the nested collection to the parent collection and dont affect the app with any nasty recycling behavior.

Comment: I am not sure if I correctly understood your question, however for passing data you may use "Delegate" pattern. Here is some Brian Voong video for that (since you like his teaching) : https://youtu.be/L2x2Yjoe-T4  Will that suit your needs?